# Toda imagem no android deve ser tratada como um bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable

Estava tendo um problema com o carregamento de imagens num *TextView*, quando me deparei com uma duvida bem idiota, rs, alguém saberia responder?

É seguinte, tava tentando carregar uma imagem grande(alta resolução) como *background* de um *TextView*, dai descobri que teria que redimensionar a imagem para não dar problema.
Até ai tudo bem, porem me perguntei, no fim das contas no android toda imagem é um *bitmap*???

Porque estava carregando a imagem .jpg da pasta drawable, direto como recurso (`txt.setBackgroundResource()`) sequer estava usando a classe *Bitmap*, no entanto no *logcat* de erro dizia **"problemas ao carregar bitmap"** (algo assim).

Então a duvida é: não importa se eu estou trabalhando com um *drawable* (R.drawable.img), uma imagem vinda de uma *url*, ou um bitmap, o android, internamente vai trabalhar/transformar, tudo em *bitmap*?

Sei que é uma duvida idiota, mas se alguém puder me esclarecer, eu agradeço. E também, não importa de onde venha a imagem, sempre devo redimensiona-la como se fosse um bitmap?

Comment: Veja como a pergunta ficou bem mais fácil de ler após a minha edição. Como ele estava, a minha primeira reacção foi nem sequer lê-la. Veja [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) os recursos que pode utilizar para formatar perguntas e respostas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Toda imagem no android deve ser tratada como um bitmap?

Depende.

**Sim**, porque [Bitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) é a classe de eleição para trabalhar com imagens cujo formato representa um mapa de *bits*.
Um mapa de *bits* é uma matriz de bits que especifica a cor de cada pixel numa matriz rectangular de pixeis.

Existem vários formatos(de arquivo) para representar esse mapa, o *Bitmap* suporta *JPEG*, *PNG* e *WebP*(Android 4.0+).

**Não**, porque a maioria dos métodos aceitam como parâmetro um *Drawable*.
Um [Drawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html) é uma abstracção geral para "algo que pode ser desenhado." Ele pode tomar uma variedade de formas, entre elas a de um *Bitmap*.

Para criar um *Bitmap* a partir de um *Drawable* use:

```
Bitmap bipmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                                             R.drawable.icon_resource);
```

Para criar um *Drawable* a partir de um *Bitmap* use:

```
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
```

A ler na documentação do Android:

- [Drawable Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)
- [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)
- [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)

Comment: Oi, obrigada. Só + 1 coisa, se eu devo checar sp todas as imgs (p/ redimensiona-las) e isso só pode ser feito através de bitmap, não é + fácil já trabalhar sp usando o bitmap e criar um método utilitário q faça esse redimensionamento?

Comment: Se a imagens existem na sua aplicação(pasta res/drawable) elas já devem ser colocadas lá com as dimensões pretendidas. Se vierem de arquivos ou da web e se forem grandes deve ser redimensionadas. No primeiro caso use *Drawable* no segundo *Bitmap*. Veja na documentação [isto](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) e [isto](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Comment: As imagens já existem sim. São imagens baixadas da internet (wallpapers de grd resolução) q eu vou armazenar na pasta drawable junto com o app. Porem minha duvida é: se não adianta eu armazenar uma img de 6000px de larg por ex, pq o android não vai conseguir exibir mesmo, com qual resolução eu devo deixar essa img p/ por na pasta xxhdpi (considerando apenas essa) de modo q ela fique boa em qq dispositvo c/ resolução xxhdpi? Ou seja esses 6000px de larg devem virar qts px p/ ser colocados na pasta xxhdpi?

Comment: Não é fácil responder a isso. Comece por responder a esta pergunta: 
Qual é a dimensão(largura x comprimento) que quero que ela tenha no Android? Depois leia [isto](http://www.tivix.com/blog/perfect-resource-image-size-dpi-for-any-android-de/) como introdução e [isto](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing) para algo mais completo.