# Android - Qual a diferença entre Bitmap e Drawable?

Tags: android

Eu estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo que faz um CRUD para preencher informações na tela. Uma dessas informações são fotos.

Eu gostaria de saber melhor a diferença entre esses dois objetos para descobrir qual seria o mais correto a ser aplicado.

Comment: Relacionado: [Toda imagem no android deve ser tratada como um bitmap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/145796/2541)

Answer (score 4):

Drawable é algo que pode ser desenhado. Por exemplo. layout, imagem vetorial (linha, círculo), fonte, imagem e assim por diante

Bitmap - é um tipo específico de Drawable que é imagem, como: PNG, JPEG ou mais

Comment: Acredito que os Bitmaps do Android não sejam compactados. Eles podem vir de arquivos .jpeg ou .png mas seu formato na memória é o de "matriz de bits" descompactada.